# how to write CSV files to separate folders from one bash script

Tags: bash, shell, awk, command-line

I have a bash script where I'm passing in variables, searching through files for matches using 'awk', and then writing the results to CSV. I want to create a new directory that takes the name of the variables given, and then write to that folder. Here's what I have so far:

```
#!/bin/sh
sport1 = "soccer"
sport2 = "baseball"


awk -var1=$sport1 -v var2=$sport2 -F, '$1 ~ var1 && $2 ~ var2' sports_file.csv > output_sports_file.csv
```

Instead of writing output_sports_file.csv to that same directory, I'd like to create a directory called "soccer_baseball", but dynamically so it takes the variables sport1 and sport2 and creates a new directory based on those two variable names string concatenated. Then I want to write output_sports_file.csv to that directory.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

```
... 
newdir="${sport1}_${sport2}"
mkdir -p "$newdir"

...
awk ... > "${newdir}"/output_file
```